# Hive to limit list of files scanning through while querying external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have created an **external hive table** which represents a large number of files. I do have **partitions** to increase select performance, still there are a quiet large number of files with in one single partition.

My partition looks something like `<TypeofFile>/<Year>/<Month>/*.gz`. In this partition structure, Hive scan through entire month of files even when I want to search for a specific date because of the fact I do not have partition to specific date. I am getting `too many partition` error when I add date as part of partition. 

I do have date & timestamp in all file names. *Is there any way to let hive map through a subset of files.* 
[INPUT__FILE__NAME](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) doesn't looks to limit the number of files mappers running through. 
Any other ideas will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: what is the type of partition? dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more directory as week:

TypeofFile/Year/Month/Week/*.gz